# What license does the auto-generated code of Webpack have?

Tags: licensing

When I pack my application, Webpack generates additional code into the bundle output file(s). Under which license is this code and am I not obliged to include that license into the source code (as it is done with packages like jQuery, Lodash, etc.)?

Please note, this question refers to the Webpack generated (frame) code in the bundle output. Not the code of the included packages or the code of webpack, which is used for the development (MIT).

Comment: This is a very interesting question, and difficult to answer. There has been an article on this by WIPO https://www.wipo.int/wipo_magazine/en/2017/05/article_0003.html which I found interesting to read. But it does not give a definite answer, as IP law has not anticipated this case. The answer might be country-specific, which many of us will find frustrating to deal with.